# MYSQL getting duplicate values from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, inner-join

I have mysql table with three fields

```
host              ipaddress      date
----              ---------      -----
server1.abc.com   10.1.1.1      2011-10-18 22:45:16
server1           10.1.1.1      2011-12-19 21:56:46
server2           11.1.1.1      2011-12-18 21:56:46
server2.abc.com   11.1.1.1      2011-12-17 21:56:46

Here,
host --> varchar
ipaddress --> varchar
date ---> datetime
```

I want to select `host` in the table which have duplicate entries for `ip`
I only want to check duplicate entry for host only if `date like '2011-12-19%'`

From above table, my result should satisfy condition `date like '2011-12-19%'`

```
host              ipaddress      date
----              ---------      -----
server1.abc.com   10.1.1.1      2011-10-18 22:45:16
server1           10.1.1.1      2011-12-19 21:56:46
```

I have written following query but getting 0 rows

```
select * from table p1
group by p1.ipaddress having count(*) >= 2
and p1.date like '2017-12-19%' 
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub-query t2 returns ipaddresses that have at least 2 rows, and at least one of the for that specific date. `JOIN` with t2's result.

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select ipaddress
      from tablename
      group by ipaddress
      having count(*) >= 2
         and count(case when CAST(date AS DATE) = '2017-12-19' then 1 end) > 0) t2
  on t1.ipaddress = t2.ipaddress
```

According to ANSI SQL `date` is a reserved word, so you may have to delimit it. (Back-ticks?)

Comment: The query is working fine for me. I also want to delete the rows from the output where date is `NOT like '2011-12-19%' `   I have updated my question

Comment: Accept this answer and ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select host
from table p1
where CAST(p1.date AS DATE) = '2017-12-19' 
group by p1.host
having count(distinct p1.ipaddress) >= 2;
```

You need:

- Group by `host`, so when you count the ip address you get the correct count.
- Use `WHERE` clause, and since the date is a datetime, don't use a wildcard.
- SELECT host only.
- If you want to select extra columns other than host, you will need an extra query.

**Note that:** There is something wrong in what you are trying to do. How the condition `date like '2011-12-19%'` should return the expected results like dates `2011-10-18 22:45:16` and `2011-12-19 21:56:46`. I think you are misunderstanding the wild card. You cannot use the wild card this way, you can use the dates operators and conditions since it is a datetime column.

- [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12298/3)

Comment: I am getting 0 rows but i should get 2 rows as output

Comment: No you should get 0 rows, there is only one row with has the date `'2011-12-19'` in the result set, Check the last note in my answer. How the condition `date like '2011-12-19%'` should return the expected results like dates `2011-10-18 22:45:16` and `2011-12-19 21:56:46` the dates are in different months and not even clause to that date.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that;

```
select t1.host from table t1 inner join
(select p1.ipaddress,max(p1.date) as date from table p1
where cast(p1.date as Date) = '2017-12-19'
group by p1.ipaddress 
having count(*) > 1) t2 
ON t1.ipaddress = t2.ipaddress and t1.date = t2.date
```

I strongly suggest you, don't compare the date fields as `like`.